# How to use the sys module in Python with a text file

Tags: python-3.5

Let's say I have a text file, adding.txt. In there I have the following:
22
25
I have a python script, add.py which has a function to add the 22 and 24 from the text file.

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b


import sys    # you must import "sys" to read from STDIN
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()   # read in the input from STDIN

a = lines[0]
b = lines[1]


print(add(a, b)) # should give 47
```

How should I run this script using the sys module?
I am using Pycharm. Thank you. I want to learn how to use the sys module using text files.

Comment: Are you expecting to specify the input file or the numbers to add via terminal arguments?

Comment: I want to specify the input file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

def add(a, b):
    return a + b

import sys    # you must import "sys" to read from STDIN
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()   # read in the input from STDIN

a = int(lines[0])
b = int(lines[1])

print(add(a, b)) # should give 47

Then go on the command prompt, type:
pathname of python file < pathname of text file
add.py.py < adding.txt

the whole pathnames could be added instead